# Rewrite within a folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is very basic but still eludes me, even after studying the relevant stackoverflow pages.

I want this

```
mysite.net/special/
```

to return this (the index here)

```
mysite.net/info/special/
```

showing the requested address in the browser, not the longer actual address.

The closest I’ve got (with this in the root htaccess) is

```
RewriteRule ^special/$ info/special/ {QUERY_STRING}
```

but it’s wrong.

I had thought this is a direct match-and-replace, but apparently not.

RewriteEngine is on.

Guidance appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^special/$ info/special/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

[RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html):

R=301: redirect permanently

QSA: combine query string

L: last rule

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming index as index.php for your index file. we are rewriting to your existing url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/special/$
RewriteRule ^ info/special/index.php [L]
```

Comment: @Ben – Thank you. In my browsers (Ffx, Saf), both of these forms return the correct page, but show the full actual address, not the shorter requested address – as it were a redirect. Caches have been cleared. This is good enough for the purpose, but I’m wondering why it might be happening, and what it might need to work correctly.

Comment: Well, uhh it is strange that it is redirecting, you sure don't have some other rule working or some other htaccess is there.

Comment: It works now. After relentless testing it started working for no visible reason. Upstream htaccess and other rules were fine. Maybe a cache weirdness? Thank you. For others who may see this page: these two solutions both work.